# global vars vs local vars

Tags: variables, global-variables, local-variables

I have a program that constantly calls a function. In my function i use variables that are only used inside of that function. Is it better "Style" to have these variables as global so that they are not constantly being created or better to have them in the function since they are irrelevant for the rest of the program.

Thanks

Comment: What language as in some there is another way and what type are the variables as for many it won't matter

Comment: its in c++ and its a range of different type variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is correct. You want to avoid global scope variables. Let the compiler or interpreter take care of any memory usage optimization. If you go down the other road you will be in a world of hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Standard practice would have you keep the variables within the scope that they're needed. In your case, these variables would be only local, so declare them and consume them locally. The logic for global variables would generally be for cross application access.

Answer (score 1):

If you have classes and functions in it, its absolutely the best to have a local variables in the functions and if you need some variable, that is used in more functions in the same object set private global variables. 
Try to dont use global public variables, you never know who or what will change it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what language you are using but generally it is best practice not to declare a variable as global if it is only needed in one method.

This is also more memory efficient as the variable only uses up memory when the function that holds it is called.

Have a look at this [link](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) for more information on why global variables should be avoided when possible.

Answer (score 0):

The performance cost of allocating local (auto) variables is effectively nil. These variables are allocated relative to the stack pointer and are already part of your stack frame. There is no performance hit for local variables.

If you need a variable to maintain a value between calls to your function, just declare it as a static local rather than global.

Comment: No true (in C++) as the variables could be complex classes

Comment: OP was asking for a best practice.